# Calculate $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\epsilon x^3+1} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\epsilon x^3+1} dx$

I tried to use:
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\epsilon x^3} dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+0} dx=1$$
However I have a problem to find $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x) \rightarrow 1$ because when I will take $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+a}, a > 0$ then I have $\int_0^1 f(x)=\frac{1}{1+a}$. 
Have you got any ideas?

Comment: What's the connection between the question in the title and the question in the body?

Comment: Just use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Alternatively, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh, I'm really sorry, firstly I had a trouble with a task which was in a title but during the writing post I found the answer. However the next I meet this problem but forget about change the title. I edited this post

Answer (score 2):

Since $\epsilon>0,$ you have $f_\epsilon (x)\leq f(x),$ where $f_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon x^3}$ and $f(x)=1.$ By dominated convergence theorem ($f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$), $f_\epsilon(x)\to f(x)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ so $\int_0^1 f_\epsilon(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\to \int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1.$

Answer (score 1):

When $\epsilon$ is very small you get something which looks like

$$\int_0^1 1~ dx=1$$

so just try to see if the difference between your integral and $1$ tends to $0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. You have 
\begin{align} 
\left|\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\epsilon x^3} dx -1\right| &= \left| \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\epsilon x^3} dx -\int_0^1 1~dx \right| \\
&= \left|\int_0^1 \frac{-\epsilon x^3}{1+\epsilon x^3} dx \right| \\ 
&\leq \int_0^1 \frac{\vert\epsilon x^3\vert}{\vert1+\epsilon x^3\vert} dx \\
&\leq \epsilon.
\end{align}
So $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\epsilon x^3} dx\longrightarrow1\quad\text{as}\quad \epsilon\to 0^+ . $$